# Find and take a part of url and replace it with a new created url using REGEX

Tags: c#, regex

I have an HTML string which conatains

```
"<a href="http://387743@adam.tv">"
```

I need to create a new url using this number (387743)
and replace the current url in the href="" with the new url i've created.

any Idia how to take this number from the url ?
if possible with REGEX

Comment: `@"(?<=http://)\d+"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=<a.*?href="")http://(\d*)@adam.tv(?="")");
```

This would match all your urls and it has a group containing the number you want.